# Spring boot Netflix zuul delays request to microservice

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul

Am using spring boot Netflix zuul router version 2.1.1, we are doing a performance test with two services and the two services have a stubbed response. Our requirement Is to test with a Tps of 15 concurrently both the services. And the Response time of stub is 8 seconds, I checked the elapsed time for both the services and I did find that both services are taking an 8.4 seconds to respond. While we reached the TPS to 10.5 one of the service reached average response time to 11.5 seconds and the second service took like 9.5 seconds. Our Target is 15 TPS and test the service till 40 TPS to check the limit of our services. Am suspecting zuul Netflix router, as I tweaked the threads to 100 for tomcat I saw improvement from 12.5 to 11.5 seconds. Please let me know where am missing. What should I do to improve performance. Am not using eureka and I use routes to connect. Currently the limit is 200 with a refresh limit of 1 second.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Can you post the solution if you have resolved the issue?

Comment: zuul:
  host: #Changes to this property requires service restart
    socket-timeout-millis: -1
    max-per-route-connections: 400
    max-total-connections: 4000
    #max-per-route-connections: 20000
    #max-total-connections: 60000
    #ribbon-isolation-strategy: THREAD
  ribbon-isolation-strategy: semaphore 
  semaphore:
    max-semaphores: 4000

Comment: @HamzaAliSiddiqui, these settings saved me, so here semaphores let's you handle more requests parallelly, sorry for the late response, I just logged in to stack overflow.